# Discrete math prove sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I am wondering if my answer to this problem is correct.

Statement: $\forall{A,B,C}:[A\subseteq B\subseteq C]\wedge[C\times B\subseteq B\times A]\implies[A=B=C]$.

Question: is the above statement true or false?

Answer: true.

Proof: x ∈ B × A and x ∈ C × B for some a ∈ A and b ∈ B which gives us a ∈ A ⊆ B ⊆ C => a ∈ B and a ∈ C also we get b ∈ B ⊆ C => b ∈ C så we get x = (a,b) ∈ C × B and x ∈ B × A.

Is this proof enough or even correct?

Can someone tell me if I'm right or wrong?

Comment: It's true only if $B\ne \emptyset$.(If $B\ne \emptyset$ and the hypotheses hold, then $A\ne \emptyset$ too.)

Comment: I did some translation to LaTex. Feel free to follow that line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is not true.

If $A=B=\varnothing$ then the conditions are satisfied for *every* set $C$.

**edit**.

The statement is true under the extra condition that $B\neq\varnothing$.

Let it be that $b_0\in B$.

If $c\in C$ then $\langle c,b_0\rangle\in C\times B\subseteq B\times A$ and we conclude that $c\in B$.

Proved is now that $C\subseteq B$ and combining this with $B\subseteq C$ we conclude that $B=C$.

If $b\in B$ then $b\in C$ (see above) so $\langle b,b\rangle\in C\times B\subseteq B\times A$ and we conclude that $b\in A$.

Proved is now that $B\subseteq A$ and combining this with $A\subseteq B$ we conclude that $A=B$.

Comment: how did you get that C⊆B and B⊆A ?

Comment: Do you agree that $\langle c,b_0\rangle\in B\times A$ implies $c\in B$? And that $\langle b,b\rangle\in B\times A$ implies $b\in A$? Have a second look at my answer.